# How to run redux-router's basic example

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-router, redux

I'm trying to use [redux-router](https://github.com/rackt/redux-router), and I'm trying run the [basic example](https://github.com/rackt/redux-router/tree/master/examples/basic). But Simpley,

```
npm start
```

doesn't work, with error message below

```
node: bad option: -r
```

I'm beginner for js modern eco-system. Could you tell me how to run this sample?

Answer (score 3):

You need to upgrade your version of node.

The command being run is

```
node -r babel/register server.js
```

I'm not sure when the `-r` flag was introduced but it's definitely there in `v4.1.1`

You might want to try somethingl like [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) to manage your node versions.

Comment: Thank you. Surely it did work as I updated to `v4.1.1`. And I try again,  
  
    npm start
  
I found another error message like below  
  
`ERROR in ./index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'react' in /Users/ushisantoasobu/Desktop/redux-router/redux-router/examples/basic
 @ ./index.js 7:13-29`

Comment: have you run `npm install`?

Answer (score 0):

I would look in to using [redux-simple-router](https://github.com/rackt/redux-simple-router) as it is much simpler to use.

**redux-simple-router** compared to *redux-router* is:

- Much smaller and simpler. You don't need to learn another library on top of everything else.
- Encourages direct access of react-router APIs. Need server-side rendering, or something else advanced? Just read react-router's docs.
- Only stores the current URL and state, whereas redux-router stores the entire location object from react-router.

Follow one of the these 2 examples to get up and running:

- [redux-simple-router-example](https://github.com/StevenIseki/redux-simple-router-example)
- [redux-frontend-boilerplate](https://github.com/tj/frontend-boilerplate)